# When does the integral of $\log z$ over a curve vanish?

Tags: complex-analysis

It is from Ahlfors.

> Describe a set of circumstances under which the formula $$\int_\gamma \log z dz = 0 $$ is meaningful and true.

Obviously any closed curve $\gamma$ whose winding number around the origin is 0 will make the integral vanish. There are also certainly other solutions, even when we restrict $z$ on the real axis. But is there a way to systematically find all such curves?

Comment: does random have a precise probabilistic meaning here? If yes can you give it?

Comment: Presumably "random" wasn't meant here but rather "arbitrary." In mathematics, random has a specific meaning (drawn from a probability distribution) rather than "just give me one" which is what arbitrary is for.